# Camera Roll adding borderColor

Tags: javascript, react-native, stylesheet

So I want to create a beautiful UI of Camera Roll that has a `borderColor` instead of `margin` or `padding` because it will make the images do not fit on the width of the screen. I do not want to add `borderColor` to the right and left the side of the images too. It just likes on Instagram.

This is what I want to achieve:

[image]

Here are my codes:

CameraRoll.js

```
  setIndex = (index) => {
if (index === this.state.index) {
  index = null
}
this.setState({ index });
};

getPhotos = () => {
CameraRoll.getPhotos({
  first: 200,
  assetType: 'All'
})
.then(res => {
  this.setState({ 
    photos: res.edges,
  });
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.log('Error image: ' + err);
});
};

render() {
return(
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Image 
      source={{uri: this.state.pickedImage}} 
      style={styles.image}
    />
    <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollView} showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
      {this.state.photos.map((photos, index) => {
        return(
          <TouchableHighlight 
            style={{opacity: index === this.state.index ? .5 : 1}}
            onPress={() => this.setState({pickedImage: photos.node.image.uri})}
            key={index}
            underlayColor='transparent'
          >
            <Image
              style={[{width: width / 3, height: width /3}]}
              source={{uri: photos.node.image.uri}}
              resizeMode='cover'
            />
          </TouchableHighlight>
        );
      })}
    </ScrollView>
  </View>
); 
}
}
```

Comment: You can use `Flatlist`

Comment: @hongdevelop and then?

Answer (score 0):

> Change style of TouchableHighlight or Image, adding borderColor:"red", borderWidth:10

```js
setIndex = (index) => {
if (index === this.state.index) {
  index = null
}
this.setState({ index });
};

getPhotos = () => {
CameraRoll.getPhotos({
  first: 200,
  assetType: 'All'
})
.then(res => {
  this.setState({ 
    photos: res.edges,
  });
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.log('Error image: ' + err);
});
};

render() {
return(
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Image 
      source={{uri: this.state.pickedImage}} 
      style={styles.image}
    />
    <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollView} showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
      {this.state.photos.map((photos, index) => {
        return(
          <TouchableHighlight 
            style={{
              opacity: index === this.state.index ? .5 : 1,  
              borderColor:"red", borderWidth:10
           }}
            onPress={() => this.setState({pickedImage: photos.node.image.uri})}
            key={index}
            underlayColor='transparent'
          >
            <Image
              style={[{width: width / 3, height: width /3}]}
              source={{uri: photos.node.image.uri}}
              resizeMode='cover'
            />
          </TouchableHighlight>
        );
      })}
    </ScrollView>
  </View>
); 
}
}
```

Comment: As I said, i only want to add `borderColor` only in the right and left. For example, I have 3 column of images, in 1st column, I just want to apply `borderRightWidth` without the `borderLeftWidth` , 2nd column only `borderRightWidth` and without `borderLeftWidth` too. In last column no `borderWidth` and all column have `borderTopWidth`

Comment: May be You are use..   borderLeftColor;"red", borderRightColor:"red"

Comment: Ow yea you're right, but the camera roll is now only 2 rows, from 3 rows to 2 row because of the `borderRightWidth`. What is the perfect styling for this to fit perfectly?